# 'OAuthToken' does not exist in the namespace 'Twitter4j.Auth'

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am using Visual Studio with Mono for Android and try to bind a Java Library (twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar) to my solution. I followed the instructions of this link http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar). When I build the Library project I get these errors:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'OAuthToken' does not exist in the namespace 'Twitter4j.Auth' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Error   4   The type or namespace name 'ResponseListImpl' does not exist in the namespace 'Twitter4j.Internal.Json' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\elanast\Documents\Visual Studio

And 3 more.

Do yoy have any idea why is this happenning? Do I have to change/add something to Metadata.xml file of the library project?

Comment: Found out the solution. I had to change Metadata.xml file and add some attributes.

Comment: Can you share the solution? I'm receiving the same error and I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

I too happened upon this problem recently. I didn't need all the Twitter4j functionality available to call through managed code, and eventually resorted to excluding some of the classes and interfaces from the generated wrapper.

For Twitter4j v3.0.4 (the core .jar only), this is the `Metadata.xml` file I ended up using:

```
<metadata>

    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='twitter4j.auth']/class[@name='OAuthToken']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='twitter4j.conf']/class[@name='ConfigurationBase']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='twitter4j.internal.json']/class[@name='EntityIndex']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='twitter4j.internal.json']/class[@name='TwitterResponseImpl']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='twitter4j.internal.json']/class[@name='ResponseListImpl']" />

    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='twitter4j']/interface[@name='ResponseList']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='twitter4j']/interface[@name='PagableResponseList']" />

</metadata>
```